# jQuery - colorpicker each() and $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm using the color picker from http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ and it works great, but I need multiple color inputs on a page, but initializing each one would be crazy. So I wrapped the initialization code in an `each()` accompanied by `this`. I'm trying to change the background color and value `onchange`. It works fine when I target it using an id or class, but when replaced with `this`, lines 12 and 13 of my fiddle don't work. The initial `this` works on targeting each input though.

Why is this happening? (or not rather)

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stinkysGTI/7ked3chg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear from the documentation, but the colorPicker stores a reference to the element it's called on in jQuery's `data`, and you can access it like this.

```
$('.color-picker').ColorPicker({
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        var el = $(this).data('colorpicker').el;
        $(el).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex).val('#' + hex);
    }
});
```

Note that you don't need an each loop at all, the plugin is initialized on all elements matching the selector

The reason it doesn't work with `this` is because the plugin sets `this` to the colorPicker, i.e. the box that pops up, not the input.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ked3chg/1/)

Comment: Ah, ok. That worked perfectly. How did you determine what it was assigning `this` to the box?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong `this`. Try defining a variable in the outermost selector method and use that instead of `$(this)`:

```
$('.color-picker').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    $(this).ColorPicker({
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            self.css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            self.val('#' + hex);
        }
    });
});
```